# When clicking on UITableview cell, app quits, sometimes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Have an app that has UITableview with a textfield.  Occasionally, when I click on the cell to enter text, the app abruptly ends, but only sometimes.  There appears to be no series of actions to duplicate, most of the time the keyboard comes up and there is no problem.  I've tried to "walk" through the process but it never fails then.

Any ideas how to track this down or things that you may have had a similar issue.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and share a [example] showing any relevant code. Otherwise it is just a guessing game. See also [ask].

Comment: If crashes? If so, there is no error message in console?

Comment: Right, no error messages just quits app.  Its not a code problem persay, because it normally works just fine.  I'm looking for some input on how to debug such a problem.  Memory issue, too many variables, process working in background that gets terminated.  I have no idea how to track this down.  I have asked many questions on SO and thank you for the welcome but I need some expert advice not silly "how to ask" links.

Comment: Silly how to ask links are often shared with new users (as based on your reputation) to point them to suggestions to improve the question with as much relevant information as possible. That being said, first thing I would do is enabling exception breakpoints in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that?